# How to publish sbt .zip file on sonatype nexus repository?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I have zip file in sbt project's target>universal folder, for publishing this zip on nexus repository i have added code below

```
import com.typesafe.config._
import play.Project._
import play.PlayJava
```

//Here I have externlised sbt properties.

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()

name := conf.getString("name_prop")

version := conf.getString("version_prop")

scalaVersion := conf.getString("scala_version")

val nexusProperty = conf.getString("nexus_prop")

val snapRelNo = conf.getString("Snapshot_Release_NO")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala);

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(jdbc, anorm, cache, ws)

resolvers ++= Seq(
"Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
"snapshots" at "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
```

//specified dependencies here
    )
    releaseSettings

```
credentials += Credentials(file(".") / "project" / ".credentials")

lazy val dist = com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.NativePackagerKeys.dist

  val publishDist = TaskKey[sbt.File]("publish-dist", "publish the dist artifact")

  lazy val publishSettings = sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin.releaseSettings ++ Seq(
    publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false,
    publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false,
    publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false,
    publish <<= (publish) dependsOn dist,
    publishLocal <<= (publishLocal) dependsOn dist,
    artifact in publishDist ~= {
      (art: Artifact) => art.copy(`type` = "zip", extension = "zip")
    },
    // disable using the Scala version in output paths and artifacts
    crossPaths := false,
    // publish to Artefactory
    organization := nexusProperty,
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    pomIncludeRepository := {
      x => false
    },
    publishDist <<= (target in Universal, normalizedName, version) map { (targetDir, id, version) =>
      val packageName = "%s-%s" format(id, version)
      targetDir / (packageName + ".zip")
    },
    publishTo <<= version {
      (v: String) =>
        val repo = nexusProperty;// FILL IN HERE
        if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
         Some("snapshots" at repo + "libs-snapshot-local")
        else
         Some("releases" at repo + "libs-release-local")
    }
  ) ++ addArtifact(artifact in publishDist, publishDist)

  val main = play.Project(appName,
    dependencies = appDependencies,
    settings = playScalaSettings ++ publishSettings
  ).settings(
    version <<= version in ThisBuild 
  )


Its giving me error for play object as "error: object Project is not a member of package play import play.Project._" and if I remove this then error for this appears "val main = play.Project(appName,"

Please let us know the solution for this.
Thanks in advance.                 ^
```

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Using-Sonatype.html?